# Show values that occur certain number of times in particular column

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to show values that meet my condition only, which is number of occurences-based.
Assuming the following table:

```
+--------------+----------------+  
| account_id   | campaign_id    |  
+--------------+----------------+  
|        234   |         980    |  
|        893   |         458    |  
|        234   |         178    |  
|        097   |         741    |  
|        893   |         584    |  
|        893   |         452    |  
|        109   |         789    |  
+--------------+----------------+
```

I need to show account_ids that only have two or more campaign_ids. So for the aforementioned table the result should be:
`234`
`893`

using `count` at `where` expression is not possible. I've used:
`CASE WHEN count(account_id) >= 2 
      THEN es.entity_name
    ELSE NULL

  END AS Live_date`

However, It got so many records have nothing to do with my query. Most of the related questions I found talk about finding the number of occurences rather than use it as a condition. Is there any other solution for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try using `HAVING` Clause:

```
select 
  account_id 
From YourTable 
group by account_id 
having count(*)>=2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select account_id
from   table
group by account_id
having count(*) >= 2
```